# Open closed app with iBeacon and iOS 7.1

Tags: ibeacon

I read about the new feature released with iOS 7.1
In this version the app opened when was find the iBeacon
I make more test but this feature don't work

Can you help me?

```
self.beaconRegion = [[ESTBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID
                                                        identifier:@"EstimoteSampleRegion"];
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = TRUE;
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = TRUE;

[self.beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start monitoring, not ranging, to launch an app on iBeacon detection.  This is true regardless of whether the app is already in the background or not.  Make sure you have implemented the monitoring callback methods, too.

```
[self.beaconManager startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
```

Comment: Thanks. startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion was deprecated. I use startMonitoringForRegion. What is the delegate called? And in the delegate I create the local notification?